# How to find the shape or dimension of an array of dictionaries (or dictionary of dictionaries) in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, shapes, dimensions

say i have an array of dictionaries:

```
thisdict={}
thisdict[0]={1: 'one', 2: "two"}
thisdict[1]={3: 'three', 4:'four'}
thisdict[2]={5: 'five', 6:'six'}
```

How can I find its dimesion? I'm looking for (3,2) -- 3 dictionaries, each with 2 entries.

`len(thisdict)` yields 3.

`np.shape(thisdict)`  returns ()

and

`np.size(thisdict)`  returns 1.

If I convert the dictionary to a dataframe via

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(thisdict)
```

then,

`np.size(tmp)` = 18

and

`np.shape(tmp)` =(6,3)

since
tmp =

[image]

which still does't give me what I'm looking for.

I guess I could do

`len(thisdict)` followed by

`len(thisdict[0])`

to get the two dimensions I'm interested in, but I assume there is a better way.  What is the "correct" way of getting these two dimensions?

Comment: is the length of entries if fixed? I mean `thisdict[0]` can have 2 entries but `thisdict[1]` can have 3 entries

Comment: thank you.  In my case, yes - all the dictionaries in the array of dictionaries all have the same number of entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `len(thisdict)` and `len(thisdict[0])`, provided that the `0`-key will always exist and all sub-dictionaries have the same length. If not, you could use something along the lines of

```py
def dict_dims(mydict):
    d1 = len(mydict)
    d2 = 0
    for d in mydict:
        d2 = max(d2, len(d))
    return d1, d2
```